# Struggling to prove some limit exists?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces. If $Y$ is complete, $A\subset X$, $f:A\rightarrow Y$ is a uniformly continuous function. Prove If $x_0\in \bar{A}\backslash A$, then the limit

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0,x\in A}f(x)
\end{equation*}
exists.

My approach:
We know f is uniformly continous and that  $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x_n)$ exists so perhaps using some epsilon delta to show that they are equivalent? Would this be the right way to go?

Comment: Have you seen the proof that if $f : (0, 1) \to \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous, then $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)$ exists?  If so, then my suggestion would be to try to generalize that argument.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to show that for every sequence $x_n\rightarrow x_0$, $x_n\in A$,
$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x_n)$ exists. For if $x_n\rightarrow x_0$, $y_n\rightarrow x_0$, and if $z_{2n-1}=x_n$, $z_{2n}=y_n$ (n=1,2,3,...), then $\{f(x_n)\}$, $\{f(y_n)\}$ are subsequences of $\{f(z_n)\}$ and hence converge to the same limit.

Let $x_n\rightarrow x_0$, $x_n\in A$. $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy, so that $\{f(x_n)\}$ is Cauchy, since $f$ is uniformly continuous. Being a Cauchy sequence in a complete metric space, $\{f(x_n)\}$ converges.